# COMException not triggering AppDomain.UnhandledException event

Tags: .net, exception, dao, unhandled-exception, comexception

I have a console application with the code shown below (simplified):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionTrapper;

  InsertRow();
}

private static void InsertRow();
{
  DAO.DBEngine dbEngine = new DAO.DBEngine();
  DAO.Database db = dbEngine.OpenDatabase("database_name");
  DAO.Recordset rs = db.OpenRecordset("table_name");
  DAO.Field myField = new DAO.Field();
  rs.AddNew();
  // System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException occurs here, but only in the IDE Debugger:
  myField.Value = "oops, this value is bigger than the size of the column";
  rs.Close();
  db.Close();
}

private static void UnhandledExceptionTrapper(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
  // Log error
  Environment.Exit(1);
}
```

**Why doesn't the [COMException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comexception.aspx) trigger the [UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event?**

In my real code, the DAO stuff is in a separate class.  I tried to `catch` the COMException and throw it again like below:

```
private static void InsertRow();
{
  try
  {
    ... // See code above
    myField.Value = "oops, this value is bigger than the size of the column";
  }
  catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
  {
    throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
  }
  finally
  {
    rs.Close();
    db.Close();
  }
}
```

However, that didn't work either.  **What am I not understanding?**

Btw, this does work, but I didn't want to do it this way:

```
  catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
  {
    // Log error
    Environment.Exit(1);
  }
```

*Let the tumbleweeds begin!*